# Run a CMD comand from a key stroke?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'd like to run a certain batch when I hit some given combination of keys.

It's as simple as, when I hit, say, CTRL+D, I want to execute the command C:\scripts\run.

Is there any way to do this, perhaps with some third party software?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want http://www.autohotkey.com

It has the ability to map arbitrary keystrokes to files or programs.
Lots of examples, including ones very similar to what you're trying to do, in their quick start tutorial: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm

Comment: Another suitable option (and the project that autohotkey was built off of) is AutoIt.

Answer (score 15):

To expand on **@ckhan**'s answer, You can write an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that uses [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and the [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command. For example,

```
^x::
    Run, C:\MyScript.bat
    return
```

will launch `C:\MyScript.bat` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

---

If you don't want to use third party software, Windows offers a similar solution with shortcut (`.lnk`) files. You can create a shortcut to your script or executable and then define a **shortcut key** in the **Properties** dialog for the shortcut. The limitation of this approach is that not all key combinations are accepted. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is replaced with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

[image: shortcut key]

---

### Note:

For either method, if you want to use commands without first creating a batch file, I recommend using the `/c` (run and close) or `/k` (run and keep open) flags of `cmd.exe`. For example, you could replace `C:\MyScript.bat` above with

```
cmd.exe /c "abc"
```

to run the command `abc`.

- More: [Windows XP - CMD documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to depend on the OS. In Linux Debian 12, in the main menu under  'Keyboard Shortcuts' there is the predefined key combination for 'Run a terminal' as Ctrl+Alt+T.